# ID3DDevice::CreateTexture2D fails with E_INVALIDARG in NV12 format for certain texture heights

Tags: directx, directx-11

I have the following texture description:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc = {};
texDesc.Width = 1920;
texDesc.Height = 953;
texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_NV12;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
texDesc.BindFlags = (D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE);
texDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;
```

And I want to create the texture using the description with `ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D`:

```
HRESULT hr = _pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, 0, _ppTexOutput);
```

With the description given, `hr` is always `E_INVALIDARG`.
But it all works if `texDesc.Height` is set to, for example, 954. Also for every value the texture is created successfully if `texDesc.Format` is set to `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`.

Is it something about `DXGI_FORMAT_NV12` format which doesn't support certain texture heights/widths? Should I just use heights that divide by 2? Or is there more complicated rule behind this?

Comment: @zezanjee - this should be an answer, not a comment. Note if you enable the debug layer, it should tell you that.

Comment: @SimonMourier I made it as answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You should look at the handling of video format sizes in [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/DirectXTex/DirectXTexUtil.cpp). They are planar so have somewhat quirky size rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that format requires that both width and height are even. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgiformat/ne-dxgiformat-dxgi_format) for reference. It explicitly says that for format `DXGI_FORMAT_NV12`:

> Width and height must be even.

If you had debug layer enabled as Simon Mourier said in the comments you would already know this. I strongly advise you to enable it since it makes debugging in DirectX a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you! Although, the reference link is broken for me (try with and without VPN):
This site can’t be reached
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: @AntonSerov sorry about that, I fixed the link.

Comment: Strange thing is 1921 works for me as the width value

Comment: @AntonSerov I just tested it with odd width and debug layer indicates error: D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: A Texture2D created with the following Format (0x67, NV12) experiences aligment restrictions on the dimensions of the Resource. The dimensions, which are (Width: 1921, Height: 954), must be multiples of (Width: 2, Height: 2). [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #101: CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDDIMENSIONS]
and return value is E_INVALIDARG.

Comment: You sure you get S_OK as return value?